# Is there a word for someone who does something specifically to use it against someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

The best word I can think of to describe the person would be to call them a martyr, but I do not know if that is the proper use of the word, or if there is a better one.

I say martyr because someone with a martyr complex is someone who uses their suffering and sacrifices against someone compulsively, but someone with that condition does not have to be sacrificing specifically to use it against the person, it just happens.

I was wondering if there was a word that meant the person did it *specifically* for that purpose.

Comment: I think you are thinking of 'manipulator', rather than 'martyr'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **concoctor**, **fabricator** or **contriver** ?

Contriver I think is best suited :

A Contriver(noun) :- A person who

1.
plans with ingenuity; devise; invent:

2.
brings about or effect by a plan, scheme, or the like; manage:

3.
plots (evil, treachery, etc.).

4.
forms designs; plan.

Answer (score 2):

A *martyr* is someone who is killed for their beliefs, so I don't think it applies here.

Something like *manipulator*, *conspirator*, *betrayer*, etc. might work better. I'm not sure if there's a specific word for this circumstance.

Comment: I say martyr because someone with a martyr complex is someone who uses their suffering and sacrifices against someone compulsively, but someone with that condition does not have to be sacrificing specifically to use it against the person, it just happens. I was wondering if there was a word that meant the person did it specifically for that purpose.

Comment: @user274585 I think the objection is with your phrasing: someone with a martyr *complex* isn't necessarily a *martyr*.

Answer (score 0):

I think this person performing their actions out of **[spite](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spite).**

> [noun] A desire to hurt, annoy, or offend someone.
>
> [verb] Deliberately hurt, annoy, or offend (someone)